# Select all rows from table in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want get all rows of ref table : ciudad

```
public function actionGetCiudades(){
    $model = ciudad::model()->findAll();
    $lCiudades = array();
    $i=0;

    $dataReader = Yii::app()->db->createCommand( 'SELECT * FROM ciudad' )->query();
    foreach( $dataReader as $row ) {
        $ciudad = new ciudad;
        echo $row->ciudadid.":".$row->estadoid.":".$row->ciudaddsc.":".$row->activo;
        echo "<br/";
        unset( $ciudad );

    }
```

Unfortunately, output is :

```
:::
```

But I have 700+ rows in my table.

What's wrong???

UPDATE :

var_dump($dataReader) -->

```
 array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(1) "1" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "1" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(15) "VALLE DE MEXICO" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(1) "2" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "1" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(6) "TOLUCA" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(1) "3" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "1" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(11) "ATLACOMULCO" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [3]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(1) "4" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "2" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(14) "AGUASCALIENTES" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [4]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(1) "5" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "2" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(18) "SAN JOSE DE GRACIA" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [5]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(1) "6" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "2" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(19) "PABELLON DE ARTEAGA" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [6]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(1) "7" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "2" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(8) "CALVILLO" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [7]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(1) "8" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "2" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(19) "ENCARNACION DE DIAZ" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [8]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(1) "9" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "2" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(15) "RINCON DE ROMOS" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [9]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "10" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "3" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(8) "ENSENADA" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [10]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "11" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "3" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(7) "TIJUANA" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [11]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "12" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "3" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(8) "MEXICALI" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [12]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "13" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "3" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(8) "ROSARITO" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [13]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "14" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "3" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(6) "TECATE" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [14]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "15" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "3" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(7) "LA MESA" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [15]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "16" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "4" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(6) "LA PAZ" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [16]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "17" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "4" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(9) "LOS CABOS" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [17]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "18" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "4" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(7) "COMONDU" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [18]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "19" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "4" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(14) "CABOS AN LUCAS" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [19]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "20" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "4" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(17) "SAN JOSE DEL CABO" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [20]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "21" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "4" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(19) "CIUDAD CONSTITUCION" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [21]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "22" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "5" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(8) "CAMPECHE" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [22]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "23" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "5" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(17) "CIUDAD DEL CARMEN" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [23]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "24" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "5" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(9) "ESCARCEGA" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [24]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "25" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "5" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(7) "CALAKUL" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [25]=> array(4) { ["ciudadid"]=> string(2) "26" ["estadoid"]=> string(1) "5" ["ciudaddsc"]=> string(7) "CALKINI" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Code :

```
public function actionGetCiudades(){
    $lCiudades = array();
    $dataReader = Yii::app()->db->createCommand( 'SELECT * FROM ciudad' )->queryAll();
    foreach( $dataReader as $row ) {
        $ciudad->ciudadid = $row['ciudadid'];
        $ciudad->estadoid = $row['estadoid'];
        $ciudad->ciudaddsc = $row['ciudaddsc'];
        $ciudad->activo = $row['activo'];
        array_push($lCiudades, $ciudad);
        unset( $ciudad );
    }
    $json = json_encode($lCiudades);
    echo $json;


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `queryAll()` instead of `query()`. `query()` adds `limit 1` to the sql query and gets only first row matching criteria.

Comment: Changed it, but not getting better. when I print $dataReader, I see the datas, see update

Comment: queryAll() gives you an array of arrays, not objects. You are accessing your values as $row->ciudadid but should as $row['ciudadid']

Answer (score 2):

As the Question title is generic let me post a generic answer to the question.

i am using Yii 2.

to get All rows from a table without applying any where class here is how you will get.

```
$dbusers = New Users;
$users = $dbusers->find()->all();
```

Your model should look like this.

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Users extends ActiveRecord
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'id','email','type'], 'required'],
            ['id', 'numeric'],
        ];
    }
}
```